# You have to be logged in and not anonymous to perform this request in cassandra even though I access it with cassandra userid

Tags: cassandra-2.1

This is Cassandra 2.1.13 day2 for me.
I've been through 10 min. cassandra tutorial at http://www.planetcassandra.org/try-cassandra/ on my local machine.

```
% cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
% // create demo keyspace
% // create users table
% //insert a couple of row in the users table
```

Now I have a problem as you see below.

```
cassandra@cqlsh:demo> list users;
Unauthorized: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="You have to be logged in and not anonymous to perform this request"
```

I accessed to cassandra with username cassdanra, why this message came up?
Do I need to set up something else?

Answer (score 20):

This message comes up if you also have in your cassandra.yaml config settings, `authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator`. Even though you're logging in as user `cassandra`, when you have `AllowAllAuthenticator` it is effectively allowing all users and therefore does not check if you have logged in. To overcome this message, you should change the setting to `authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator` and then restart cassandra.